# PKIX path validation failed while running Grails new project

Tags: ssl, grails

I've created a new Grails 4.0.2 application and ran it, got the

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not download web.jar (org.grails.profiles:web:4.0.0)
> Could not get resource 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/profiles/web/4.0.0/web-4.0.0.jar'.
   > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/profiles/web/4.0.0/web-4.0.0.jar'.
      > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 9s
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The JDK or certificate store you are using is out of date](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11561). Update to a more recent version of your JDK distribution or add the missing certificates manually.

This is because of [Sectigo's AddTrust External CA Root Expiring May 30, 2020](https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020)